# htaccess - rewrite .php to .png in multiple subfolders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On my website I have a folder called `/banners/`. This folder contains 3 subfolders, `/small/, /medium/ and /big/`. All of the subfolders have an index.php file that require a parameter to work.

To make it a bit easier to understand:

```
/banners/ -> /small/ -> index.php?server=$id
             /medium/ -> index.php?server=$id
             /big/ -> index.php?server=$id
```

What i'm trying to do is i want to make `/banners/small/index.php?server=$id` *(and the other 2 subfolders)* to look like `/banners/small/$id.png`. Is it possible to rewrite the index pages to a .png file with only 1 htaccess file which is located in the `/banners/` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this code in your htaccess (assuming it is in `/banners/` folder like you said)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /banners/

RewriteRule ^(small|medium|big)/(.+?)\.png$ $1/index.php?server=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked :) , can't accept the answer though, need to wait 6 minutes...